# Masonry is not loading on Wordpress blog

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-masonry

I've been trying to get [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to stack my posts on this blog for the past two days:
[topheavypilesofbooks.com](http://topheavypilesofbooks.com/).  The posts should stack neatly with no whitespace.  Instead ***posts float as usual, with lots of vertical whitespace***.

This is a Wordpress blog, and I've added the javascript with the enqueue function.  According to Firebug, the javascripts are loading correctly.

The last script I load is the function to trigger Masonry, it is this:

```
    jQuery((window).load(){
  jQuery('#content').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.post',
    columnWidth : 240
  });
});
```

Comment: I also tried this to load Masonry: 
`( function($) {
var $container = $('#content');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.post'
  });
});
} ) ( jQuery );`
didn't change at all..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an error with your brackets.

Try this... I ran it on your site and it functions. Might require some tweaking, that I currently dont have time to do :)

```
jQuery(function () { 
  jQuery('#content').masonry({ 
   itemSelector: '.post', 
   columnWidth: 240 
  }); 
})
```